# How to properly unittest in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a method which does the following. Question is how do I unit test this method. I am pretty new to this Python unit testing module.

The question and solution are as follows:

```
Given a string containing of ‘0’, ‘1’ and ‘?’ wildcard characters, generate all binary strings that can be formed by replacing each wildcard character by ‘0’ or ‘1’.
Example :
Input str = "1??0?101"
Output: 
        10000101
        10001101
        10100101
        10101101
        11000101
        11001101
        11100101
        11101101
```

Solution:

```
def _print(string, index):
    if index == len(string):
        print(''.join(string))
        return

    if string[index] == "?":

        # replace '?' by '0' and recurse
        string[index] = '0'
        _print(string, index + 1)

        # replace '?' by '1' and recurse
        string[index] = '1'
        _print(string, index + 1)

        # NOTE: Need to backtrack as string
        # is passed by reference to the
        # function
        string[index] = '?'
    else:
        _print(string, index + 1)

# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":

    string = "1??0?101"
    string = list(string) #don’t forget to convert to string
    _print(string, 0)
```

Output:

```
        10000101
        10001101
        10100101
        10101101
        11000101
        11001101
        11100101
        11101101
```

**Questions:**

**1. Also, is there a way of returning a list as output instead of printing them out?**

**2. Which assert test cases are appropriate in this scenario?**

**3. What would be the best end to end test cases to cover in this case?**

**4. What could be a better approach of solving this in terms of time and space complexity?**

I have tried this which doesn't seem to work:

```
import unittest
from wildcard import _print
class TestWildCard(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_0_print(self):
        print("Start wildCard _print test: \n")
        result = 111
        self.assertEquals(_print("1?1",0),result,"Results match")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1: sure, instead of printing something, append the result to a list `result.append('some value')` and don't forget to initialise the list at the start of your code `result = []` and return it once the function is done `return result` - and probably don't call the function `_print`, but something like `bit_strings`.

ad 1: since your function is recursive, you now also need to capture the return value and add it to the result when calling the function recursively, so `result += _print(string, index + 1)`

2: you should typically think of edge cases and test them separately, or group those together that really test a single aspect of your function. There is no one way to state what the test should look like - if there were, the test framework would just generate it for you.

3: same answer as 2.

Your code becomes:

```
def bit_strings(s, index):
    result = []

    if index == len(s):
        result.append(''.join(s))
        return result

    if s[index] == "?":
        # replace '?' by '0' and recurse
        s[index] = '0'
        result += bit_strings(s, index + 1)

        # replace '?' by '1' and recurse
        s[index] = '1'
        result += bit_strings(s, index + 1)

        # NOTE: Need to backtrack as string
        # is passed by reference to the
        # function
        s[index] = '?'
    else:
        result += bit_strings(s, index + 1)

    return result


# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = "1??0?101"
    xl = list(x)  #don’t forget to convert to string
    print(bit_strings(xl, 0))
```

There's more efficient ways of doing this, but I just modified your code in line with the questions and answers.

I've renamed `string` to `s`, since `string` is a bit confusing, reminding others of the type or shadowing the (built-in) module.

As for the unit test:

```
import unittest
from wildcard import bit_strings


class TestWildCard(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_0_print(self):
        print("Start wildCard _print test: \n")
        # you only had one case here and it's a list now
        result = ['101', '111']
        # user assertEqual, not Equals
        # you were passing in a string, but your code assumed a list, so list() added
        self.assertEqual(bit_strings(list("1?1"), 0), result, "Results match")
```

When using an environment like PyCharm, it helps to call the file `test<something>.py` (i.e. have `test` in the name), so that it helps you run the unit tests more easily.

Two alternate solutions as requested in comment (one still recursive, just a lot more concise, the other not recursive but arguably a bit wasteful with result lists - just two quickies):

```
from timeit import timeit


def unblank_bits(bits):
    if not bits:
        yield ''
    else:
        for ch in '01' if bits[0] == '?' else bits[0]:
            for continuation in unblank_bits(bits[1:]):
                yield ch + continuation


print(list(unblank_bits('0??100?1')))


def unblank_bits_non_recursive(bits):
    result = ['']
    for ch in bits:
        if ch == '?':
            result = [s+'0' for s in result] + [s+'1' for s in result]
        else:
            result = [s+ch for s in result]
    return result


print(list(unblank_bits_non_recursive('0??100?1')))

print(timeit(lambda: list(unblank_bits('0??100?1'))))
print(timeit(lambda: list(unblank_bits_non_recursive('0??100?1'))))
```

This solution doesn't move between lists and strings, as there is no need and doesn't manipulate the input values. As you can tell the recursive one is a bit slower, but I prefer it for readability. The output:

```
['00010001', '00010011', '00110001', '00110011', '01010001', '01010011', '01110001', '01110011']
['00010001', '01010001', '00110001', '01110001', '00010011', '01010011', '00110011', '01110011']
13.073874
3.9742709000000005
```

Note that your own solution ran in about 8 seconds using the same setup, so the "improved version" I suggested is simpler, but not faster, so you may prefer the latter solution.

Comment: By the way, you were calling your function a method, but a method is a function defined on a class. A function is just a function.

Comment: I understand your point. Could you suggest some better ways of doing this, a more time and space efficient way perhaps? @Grismar

Comment: Some suggestions added.